# How can we find the maximum?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, functional-equations, functional-calculus

Suppose that $y=y(a(\lambda),\lambda,x)$ is a decreasing and twice continuously differentiable functional with respect to $x$ and $a(\lambda)$ is linear mapping from a space $\Lambda$ to $(0,+\infty)$. How can we find the maximum of the following function with respect to $y$, that is,

$$g(y)=-\frac{1}{2\lambda}y^2(a(\lambda),\lambda,x)+\left(\frac{a(\lambda)}{\lambda}-x\right)y(a(\lambda),\lambda,x)$$

Namely, I want to calculate

$$\max_{y(a(\lambda),\lambda,x)}\left\{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\lambda}y^2(a(\lambda),\lambda,x)+\left(\frac{a(\lambda)}{\lambda}-x\right)y(a(\lambda),\lambda,x)}_{g(y)}\right\}$$

I thing this is not a classic optimization problem since the control is a functional and not just a variable. What does it changes in such a case?

Comment: I was hoping for something like this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative...

Comment: So, let me put this dofferently, does anybody knows a theory pof optimization with respect to a functional instead of a function. I think this is related somehow with functional analysis...Can anybodey help me?